# if no value return in set double to a set number with a guard let statement

Tags: swift, xcode

in the code below its giving a warning the longitude and latitude after the else statement was never used, if my dictionary doesn't contain a value for longitude and latitude will they be set as  let longitude = Double(151.209900) and  let latitude = Double(-33.865143) ? or am i doing something wrong with the guard let statement

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
guard let latitude = dictionary["Latitude"] as? String else {
    let latitude = Double(-33.865143)            
    return 
}
guard let longitude = dictionary["Longitude"] as? String else {
    let longitude = Double(151.209900)
    return 
}       
guard let latDouble = Double(latitude) else { return }
guard let longDouble = Double(longitude) else { return }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your function and watch what happens if the dictionary has no entry for the key "Latitude". – Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 3):

The values set for latitude and longitude will never be used because their scope is limited to the `guard`

I'd probably do it like this instead:

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }


let latitude = Double(dictionary["Latitude"] as? String ?? "-33.865143")
let longitude = Double(dictionary["Longitude"] as? String ?? "151.209900")
```